# Regex doesn't match properly with customized markdown

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a custom markdown for a project, and php keeps hanging on paragraphs like this:

```
[[Test paragraph with an [insertion] here that throws off]]
```

Typically, the php command

```
$file_contents = preg_replace('/\s(\[\[)([^\]]*)(\]\])/i','<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">$2</div><br>',$file_contents);
```

Puts a nice little box around anything that is enclosed in `[[your paragraph here]]` but if you put a `]` in the paragraph, then regex never finishes the match.

I've tried putting a period in, but I need to match non-ascii characters, and as far as I have seen with my own code, the period doesn't match, for example, Arabic. Most of my paragraphs are in Arabic. Here's a sample of something I can't match:

`[[عـى أن سـليان هـو وراء نظـم هـذا السـفر [بإلهـام مـن اللـه] فحسـب لكنـه يظهـر]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\X*?` instead of second capturing group.`\X` matches any number of Unicode characters that form an extended Unicode sequence.

```
$file_contents = preg_replace('/\s(\[\[)(\X*?)(\]\])/iu','<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">$2</div><br>',$file_contents);
```

OR

```
$file_contents = preg_replace('/\s(\[\[)((?:(?!\]\])\X)*)(\]\])/iu','<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">$2</div><br>',$file_contents);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cO7uJ7/3)

Comment: That works in English, but I'm also dealing with non-ascii characters (most of the paragraphs are arabic and the . doesn't match the Arabic characters

Comment: see it works https://regex101.com/r/cO7uJ7/2 . is there a space exists before the `[[`? if not then remove the leading `\s` from the regex.

Comment: Hmm... I still think the issue is with the period. When I copy that into my code and run it off my computer, it doesn't work. The period isn't matching Arabic still.... Are you also testing on your machine or just on regex101 (great tool by the way!)

Comment: I just googled my problem of a period not matching an Arabic letter, and this page was the third result on Google.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler did you turn on the unicode modifier `u` ? Wait, let me check.

Comment: I think I found a solution. According to http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php, \X represents an extended unicode expression. I used \X instead of . and it works. Change your answer to reflect it, and I'll upvote you and make you the accepted answer. $file_contents = preg_replace('/\s(\[\[)((?:(?!\]\])\X)*)(\]\])/i','<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">$2</div><br>',$file_contents);

Comment: @PaulCrovella, I then run into problems with this example: https://eval.in/235739

Comment: Never mind that last one, it doesn't work with my code either, and I'm not sure why. When I put your recommendation in my program, it doesn't work though while my answer below does. I'm satisfied though.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_contents = preg_replace('/\s([[)((?:(?!]])\X)*)(]])/i','<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">$2</div><br>',$file_contents);
```

Finally did the trick. According to php.net, \X represents an extended unicode expression. I used \X instead of . and it works.